# No Package.XML found

Tags: apex, data-loader, workbench, custom-metadata, package.xml

Trying to deploy the Custom metadata loader ZIP file in workbench and its giving an error. Please see the below...

[image: Package.XML not found]

Following this steps : https://github.com/forcedotcom/CustomMetadataLoader

Comment: Did you import the package.xml zip file before running these steps.

Comment: I am following this steps : Download the folder custom_md_loader and zip all the files inside this folder. Package.xml should be at the top level of the zipped file.
Log in to your developer organization via workbench and deploy this zip file. (migration -> deploy) - Here I am an getting error.

Comment: set single package into true if possible in Workbench

Comment: Tried, still not working

Answer (score 3):

you should not zip the "custom_md_loader" folder, try to get in this folder and then select all folders including package.xml and click to zip [image]

Answer (score 0):

My package file was capital `P` - `Package.xml`. I've changed it to lower `p` - `package.xml` and the new name worked.